# Fatal Error aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

So I am new to app development I installed flutter as per the instruction on https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

1. Installed Flutter
2. Installed Android Studio

When I am running the app this error comes up.

[Here error msg I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXrtq.jpg)

Here's the error msg

[Fatal Error] aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.

Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.

Required by:
      project :app

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>   Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try cleaning your gradle cache

Comment: How to clear gradle cache ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

1).Close android studio.

2).Delete all the contents of below directories.

```
 C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\build-cache
 C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\cache
 C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches
```

3).Start Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!

So there was some problem in my Android SDK Path Variable which I fixed and also cleared my Gradle cache and it worked like charm.

Comment: I'm getting error on running 'flutter build appbundle' command                                                 [Fatal Error] checker-qual-2.5.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Can you please share the detailed steps about how you solved your issue ??